# Symbol lookup error on running Genymotion in XUbuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, genymotion

I'm using XUbuntu and decide to use Genymotion as Android emulator,
I download the Genymotion deb file from their site and install it and also install the Virtualbox with `apt` but when I try to run it from the launcher noting happen!

I'm trying to run it from Terminal and see the following error:

```
./genymotion
./genymotion: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpangoft2-1.0.so.0: undefined symbol: FcWeightFromOpenType
```

in Synaptic the libpango was installed!
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `sudo` to run the Genymotion and everything works!
I don't know why this happen but when run app without `sudo` get the error on below:

```
./genymotion: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpangoft2-1.0.so.0: undefined symbol: FcWeightFromOpenType
```

but if just run app with `sudo` like this: `sudo ./genymotion` everything works great!

Answer (score 1):

I assume you use xubuntu 16.10 that have newer fontconfig library. Get libfontconfig.so.1 and libharfbuzz.so.0 from xenial, you may get it from packages.ubuntu.com or use this links:

- http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/f/fontconfig/libfontconfig1_2.11.94-0ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb
- and
  http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/h/harfbuzz/libharfbuzz0b_1.0.1-1ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb

extract and copy following files:

- libfontconfig.so.1
- libfontconfig.so.1.9.0
- libharfbuzz.so.0
- libharfbuzz.so.0.10000.1

to genymotion installation folder